# Wireless is connected but no internet when PC Turns on

Tags: windows-7, internet, wireless-router

I have a PC that is connected to ADSL Modem router or 'gateway' (linksys WAG54g2) directly via Ethernet cable And a laptop and also other devices such as another laptops and smarth phones.

However when I turn on the PC or turn it off, some strange problem happens. My wireless network seems connected on laptop but there is no internet activity and can't open a webpage until I turn router off and on again manually. (other devices including the PC itself can't use the internet either)

My router configured this way:

Encapsulation: RFC 2516 PPPoE

Multiplexing: LLC

DHCP Server: Enabled

and network sharing center > IPv4 configuration is obtain IP address automatically

Tried moving the cable to another port on the gateway, didn't help.

How Can I fix this issue?

Comment: when there's "No internet connectivity" can you ping web sites by IP address?  Can you ping the router by it's IP?

Comment: @techie007 I can ping my router `192.168.1.1` but all other requests results `request time out`